Using SSMS is there any way to easily identify what alias a reference is from?
For instance let's say I have the following query in a stored procedure:
SELECT apples 
FROM Fruits T
JOIN Things T2 ON T.Id = T2.FruitId

How can I easily know which table "apples" is from? T or T2? Obviously in this example it would be easy to figure out but in some of the code I have inherited it is not at all. Multiple databases, JOINs for days, it's a pain trying to figure out what table is providing what data.

Try select apples from Fruits and select apples from Things. Only one of them will work.

It's good programming practice to qualify all columns, at least when several tables are involved.

The only foolproof way to verify whence the apples column is would be to check the definition of all tables.  For a query with only a few tables, such as this one, you can probably do this in SSMS by simply looking at the table structure on the left hand toolbar.

If you use the query designer, it adds all the corresponding table names etc (and converts * to all the individual fields). In these situations, I make a copy of the query, highlight it, and right-click to use the query designer and then save. It populates all the table names and then can be copied.

Some developer tools can help you if you wish to look into such possibilities and use them (usually free for a trial period) - they may even add the aliases for you as part of code cleanup or formatting features.

@jarlh I agree but this is a project I inherited, not one I wrote. The whole this is spaghetti and to pay that tech debt would be a cost the client wouldn't approve. Have to make do with what I've got.

Why do you need this?

One method would be to still use meaningful aliases. T1 is a terrible alias for Fruits; F would make far more sense. Consistent and sensible aliases make things far easier.

@jarlh - In order to qualify all columns you still need to figure out which table the column was coming from when faced with a query that doesn't do this so this question is perfectly valid.

@MartinSmith, I didn't address OP and claim the question as invalid. It was more of a general advice to anyone reading the question and its comments.

You can use the system function sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set, which with some limitations can tell you this information. The key point is the final parameter, asking for BROWSE information.
SELECT
  r.column_ordinal,
  r.name,
  r.source_database,
  r.source_schema,
  r.source_table,
  r.source_column
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'
SELECT apples 
FROM Fruits T
JOIN Things T2 ON T.Id = T2.FruitId
', N'', 1) AS r;

db<>fiddle
